# Continuous and dense embedding preserves orthogonality?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, orthogonality

Let $H_1=(H_1,(\cdot, \cdot)_1)$ and $H_2=(H_2,(\cdot, \cdot)_2)$ be Hilbert space such that $H_1 \subset H_2$ and $H_1$ is continuously and densely embedded in $H_2$.

**Question.** If for some $u,v \in H_1$ holds $(u,v)_1=0$, then also $(u,v)_2=0?$

It's true under this hypothesis? Or under some additional hypothesis?

I think it's true, since $H_1$ is continuously and densely embedded in $H_2$. I was able to see this fact only for some particular cases. My interest is whether it is worth more generally, which I haven't been able to prove until then.

Comment: I assume the embedding is linear?

Comment: Also, do you have any suggestion for why it's important that the embedding be dense? I imagine you would just be able to replace $H_2$ with the closure of $H_1$ in case $H_1$ isn't dense.

Comment: Take $H_1=H_2=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $T=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$. This is a (non-isometric) isomorphism which does not preserve orthogonality. So you probably need isometric embedding.

Comment: @Chrystomath It is not enough that the natural injection $ i: H_1 \rightarrow H_2 $ (which in this case I believe is the inclusion, since $H_1 \subset H_2$) satisfies: $||i(u)||_{H_2} \leq ||u||_{H_1},$ for all $u \in H_1$?

Comment: Continuous embedding only requires $\|i(u)\|_{H_2}\le c\|u\|_{H_1}$. In any case, $T=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$ satisfies this inequality with $c=1$ but does not preserve orthogonality.

Answer (score 1):

What is an embedding? Is it an isometric embedding? Because in that case this seems just true by definition. Is it just an injective linear map? Because in that case I see no reason why orthogonality should be preserved. Even just finite dimensional examples would work.

Comment: Continuous embedding means that the natural injection $i: H_1 \rightarrow H_2$ is continuous. I still think we could rewrite the continuity of $ i $ as: there exist $c\geq 0$ such that $||x||_{H_1} \leq c||x||_{H_2}$ for all $x \in H_1$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_embedding#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20one%20normed%20vector%20space%20is%20said,the%20Sobolev%20embedding%20theorems%20are%20continuous%20embedding%20theorems.).